# How do you check if a selector matches something in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In Mootools, I'd just run `if ($('target')) { ... }`.  Does `if ($('#target')) { ... }` in jQuery work the same way?

Comment: See also [Is there an `exists` function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Answer (score 800, accepted):

As the other commenters are suggesting the most efficient way to do it seems to be:

```
if ($(selector).length ) {
    // Do something
}
```

If you absolutely must have an exists() function - which will be slower- you can do:

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}
```

Then in your code you can use

```
if ($(selector).exists()) {
    // Do something
}
```

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: what is the point in this when .length does exactly the same?

Comment: This is one of the sillier plugins I've ever seen...

Comment: I have reworded the reply to emphasize that $.fn.exists is slower.

Comment: It's funny that @snover makes the exact same comment here that he does in the linked answer. Didn't get the point across the first time?

Comment: @Stevus I don't understand your question... snover and others saw two answers that were not good enough, they commented on both (two years after the answers were posted)... I saw the comments and updated my answer to take them into consideration. Which part of the sequence of events is bothering you?

Comment: I guess the example of .exists is relevant. I think the author wanted to show that you can design an exists function that could for example return true only if the length is greater than 3. So I don't think more information is anyhow silly...

Comment: other link: [learn jquery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/)

Comment: Good answer, but why `this.length>0` rather than just `this.length` in the exists() function?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie so it returns a bool and not a number

Comment: @Josef: a zero, or non-zero, number evaluates to a boolean when tested using if. As I said, it is *not* required here. :P

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie it is very bad API design to have a "exists" function that can return 3, IMO!

Comment: @Josef: And very poor code design if you are doing math on the return value of a function called `exists`... IMHO :) Actually adding a one-liner extension, like `exists()` that is 2 characters *longer* than what it replaces is silly to begin with for JS! :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie for JS that is true. (I do more with C++ where this makes sense imo) The problem with an API that has such quirks is, that **someone** will do math on the result of `exists` and when the API is fixed, things break.

Answer (score 100):

no, jquery always returns a jquery object regardless if a selector was matched or not.
You need to use .length

```
if ( $('#someDiv').length ){

}
```

Comment: This is more practical than the accepted answer's second suggestion. (Why would you introduce a slower & *longer* alternative to simply checking length!). I also note your answer was earlier +1 :)

Answer (score 22):

if you used:

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return ($(this).length > 0);}
if ($(selector).exists()) { }
```

you would imply that chaining was possible when it is not.

This would be better

```
jQuery.exists = function(selector) {return ($(selector).length > 0);}
if ($.exists(selector)) { }
```

Comment: Could you provide an example where chaining is not possible?

Comment: @TomasM: Well, `.exist()` returns a bool, on which you cannot call jQuery methods, see comments below [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/444403/3821804).

Answer (score 16):

```
if ($('#elem')[0]) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I like this for brevity. Can anyone say whether it will work everywhere .length will work?

Comment: The only case it wouldn't is if jQuery gave you an array with e.g. null (or otherwise "falsy") contents instead of DOM element objects, which would be surprising.

Answer (score 16):

I think most of the people replying here didn't quite understand the question, or else I might be mistaken.

The question is "how to check whether or not a *selector* exists in jQuery."

Most people have taken this for "how to check whether an element exists in the DOM using jQuery." Hardly interchangeable.

jQuery allows you to create custom selectors, but see here what happens when you try to use on e before initializing it;

```
$(':YEAH');
"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: YEAH"
```

After running into this, I realized it was simply a matter of checking

```
if ($.expr[':']['YEAH']) {
    // Query for your :YEAH selector with ease of mind.
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Note: The question has been changed to mean what they intended after this was posted, so this answer no longer has meaning here :)

Answer (score 15):

Yet another way:

```
$('#elem').each(function(){
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Nice, cleaner approach if you don't want to do anything special if #elem does not exist.

Comment: As an ID can only exists once, and duplicates are ignored by JS and jQuery, this may lead to confusion if you do not explain that it is a 0 or 1 situation :)

Comment: I can't believe that this answer get upvotes. This have nothing to do with existens check. Totaly wrong direction.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively:

```
if( jQuery('#elem').get(0) ) {}
```

Comment: This is no shorter than `.length` (and slower). `$('#elem')[0]` would do the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(selector, callback) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.each(function() {
        callback.call(this, ($(this).find(selector).length > 0));
    });
};
```

Comment: Why would you ever do an `each` *and a callback* if you just want to know if there was zero or more matches? I now feel more stupid than I was before I read this! -1.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the

```
    if (jQuery("#anyElement").is("*")){...}
```

Which basically checks if this elements is a kind of "*" (any element).
Just a cleaner syntax and the "is" makes more sense inside an "if"

Comment: sounds like a lot of effort, compared to just reading an existing property

Comment: This is significantly slower than the alternatives and arguably less readable. You would not introduce parsing to check the length of an array and a jQuery object behaves just like an array.

Answer (score -4):

For me `.exists` doesn't work, so I use the index :

```
if ($("#elem").index() ! = -1) {}
```

Comment: you have to create the exists() function

Comment: This is longer and slower than using `.length`. This answer is best deleted (voting to delete).

Answer (score -7):

firstly create a function:

```
$.fn.is_exists = function(){ return document.getElementById(selector) }
```

then

```
if($(selector).is_exists()){ ... }
```

Comment: This presumes the selector was an ID, not a jQuery selector as required. Best delete this answer as it is misleading. -1 & voting to delete