# Check if an object exists by its selector, return a boolean value with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to see if an object is present on the page by its selector.

This WOULD normally do it:

`startpageentry = $('#' + startpageid)`

But that doesn't return anything. I need a boolean I can put into an if statement like this:

if (startpageentry != 'false') {}

How can I do this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299802/how-do-you-check-if-a-selector-exists-in-jquery

Comment: Was 'false' a typo?  You should compare to false, not 'false'.  Or, if you know it's a boolean, you should compare with !== false.  (Or just !startpageentry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no boolean for that because it would prevent from chaining.
You could use `$(something).length>0`.
But if you need to run in over and over again, I made a little jQuery plugin which is called `doesExist()`

```
/* doesExist PLUGIN (c) MS */
/* (c) Michael Stadler(MS), */
(function($){
$.fn.doesExist = function()
{
return jQuery(this).length > 0;
};
})(jQuery);
```

The usage of it would be

```
if($('#something').doesExist()){
      //doesExist returns a boolean
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `length`:

```
var startpageentry = $('#' + startpageid).length;
```

To store boolean result, use:

```
var isPresent = $('#' + startpageid).length > 0;
```

Now `isPresent` will be true if it exists `false` otherwise.

Or simply:

```
if ($('#' + startpageid).length){
  // exists
}
else {
  // does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a Boolean with jQuery...

```
var startpageentry = !! $('#' + startpageid).length;
```

Without jQuery...

```
var startpageentry = !! document.getElementById(startpageid);
```

Of course, you don't *really* need a Boolean to test it. You could just rely on `0` being *falsey* (for the jQuery version) or `null` being *falsey* (for the non jQuery version).

Also, your *but that doesn't return anything* isn't correct. It would return a reference to the jQuery object returned. Objects in JavaScript are always *truthy*, so testing it in a condition won't tell you if the selector matched any elements or not.

Comment: `$('#' + startpageid).length > 0` will also do same thing, no need to use that operator

Comment: @Sarfraz Is `!` a naughty operator?

Comment: It forces/coerces expression into boolean, little expensive to use especially when you can avoid it :)