# jQuery has conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to write a conditional with jQuery that basically states, if `div.gathering` does not contain `a.cat-link` then do the following. I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
if($("div.gathering:contains('a.cat-link')")){
    $(".gathering").append("<a href='#"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_id"]+"div' class='cat-link' id='"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_id"]+"' rel='external'>"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_name"]+"<br />");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check if a selector exists in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299802/how-do-you-check-if-a-selector-exists-in-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this :

```
if($("div.gathering").find("a.cat-link").length == 0){
  // Conditional statement returned TRUE
}
```

jQuery selectors return arrays of objects that matched the given selector.  This is why we use the `length` property.

The method that *you* used - `$("div.gathering:contains('a.cat-link')")`
would return an empty array and when testing against any **object** that actually **exists** (even if it is an empty array) JavaScript will return `true`.

Example -

```
var nateArr = []; 
if (nateArr){
  // Do the dishes...
}else{
 // Eat some waffles...
}
```

If you test this for yourself you will never stop washing those dishes because even though the `nateArr` contains zero elements it still **exists** therefore the conditional statement will always return `true`.
<sub>And your fingers will go all wrinkly</sub>

Comment: I'm assuming !== 0 would be the opposite of this?

Answer (score 2):

try this....

```
$("div.gathering:not(:contains(a.cat-link))")
    .append("<a href='#"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_id"]+"div' class='cat-link' id='"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_id"]+"' rel='external'>"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_name"]+"<br />")
```

this will only return the div with class gathering which does not have a.cat-link....

hope this helps....

Comment: I like this - less code and it does the trick! +1.   However we do not know if there is more code inside that conditional block, so your solution *might* not work for his situation.   The more verbose methods also improve readability.  [Programs should be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/522895/558021)