# Jquery shorthand for .size()>1

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a code with a lot of `$(".blahblah").size()>0` conditions in it. I was wondering if there is a JQuery shorthand for it that eliminates the need to type `>1`.

There is a suggestion here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/selector-exists-would-be-a-nice-addition

Something like `$(...).exists()` can be handy. Is there such a thing? I couldn't find it on the Internet and I was wondering if someone knows a trick or anyone from JQuery team who knows if such feature is planned to be added?

PS. I have read this: [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299802/how-do-you-check-if-a-selector-exists-in-jquery

Comment: The forum thread you link also links to a [bug ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3842) which is closed "because `is()` already provides this functionality" (so I guess that's as close as you'll get to a built-in function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function moreThanOne(selector){
  return $(selector).length > 1;
}
```

The solution is to use function for that and also you can use `length` instead of `size()`.

From Jquery's documentation

> The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property;
>   however, the .length property **is preferred** because it does not have
>   the overhead of a function call.

Answer (score 1):

another option will be

```
if($(".blahblah")[0]) { ... }
```

if your goal is less typing

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `exists` function like this:

```
function exists(selector){
  return jQuery(selector).size() > 0;
}
```

And then you can use it like:

```
if (exists(".blahblah")) {
  // it exists
}
```

Added to jQuery `fn`:

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){
    return this.length > 0;
}
```

To use:

```
if ($(".blahblah").exists()) {
  // it exists
}
```

---

You can also use `length` property for which you don't need to type `> 0`:

```
if ($(".blahblah").length) {
  // it exists
}
```

Comment: thanks but I would go with the jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;} solution because of readability.

Comment: @AlexStack: Yeah that's better, I have updated answer with that :) BTW, you can also simply do `if ($(".blahblah").length)` without need to type `> 0`

Comment: yes, that's a good suggestion, but for code readability, I prefer to have `>0` the reason I'm looking for the `exist()` function in the first place is readability rather than speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'has' selector.

You can write:

```
$(':has(.blahblah:eq(1))')
```