# how do i find if ul contains li with id in an if condition

Tags: jquery

how do i find if ul contains li with id 'liSubTask1' exists or not in an if condition in jquery

```
 <ul id='ulTask'>
   <li id='liSubTask1'>subTask1</li>
   <li id='liSubTask2'>subTask2</li>
   <li id='liSubTask3'>subTask3</li>
   <li id='liSubTask4'>subTask4</li>
   <li id='liSubTask5'>subTask5</li>
 </ul>
```

i wanted to find out if "li with id" exists in ul then do some thing

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
if($("#ulTask #liSubTask1").length)
{
   //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The ">" symbol restricts a selector to direct descendents of the first selector:  http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

```
if ($('#ulTask > li#liSubTask4').length) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this sounds very familiar to these questions "[Is there an “exists” function for jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)" and "[How do you check if a selector exists in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299802/how-do-you-check-if-a-selector-exists-in-jquery)"

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}

if ($(selector).exists()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('ul#ulTask li#liSubTask1').length) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nextli = $("#ulTask").next(li);
var id = nextli.attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code if you want to check all the inner child elements too..

```
if($('#ulId').find('#liId').length > 0)
```